# Java JDBC - Navigate Through Records Within Database

Tags: java, swing, jdbc

I am having some trouble in returning the *NEXT* record within the database, my code currently only returns the last record entered. I have tried creating an instance of a List/ArrayList, tried adding statements to my *createStatement();* and just tried everything. I've searched the web, however, I always seem to get the last value returned. I was hoping as to whether someone could help me out. I am using .Swing and this is all executed within an ActionListener.

Essentially I want this function to get the next record in the database. As opposed to returning the last record.

```
nextEmployee.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        Connection connection = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:employeeDatabase.sqlite");
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            System.out.println("Read operation - database successfully opened");
            statement = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,
                    ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery( "SELECT * from employees" );
            while (resultset.next()) {  
                ArrayList<Employee> selectAllEmployees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
                String id = resultset.getString("id");
                String  name = resultset.getString("name");
                String  email = resultset.getString("email");
                String  gender = resultset.getString("gender");
                String  dob = resultset.getString("dob");
                String  Address = resultset.getString("address"); 
                String  Postcode = resultset.getString("Postcode");
                String  NIN = resultset.getString("NIN");
                String  JobTitle = resultset.getString("JobTitle");
                String  StartDate = resultset.getString("StartDate");
                String  Salary = resultset.getString("Salary");
                idTextField.setText(id);
                nameTextField.setText(name);
                genderTextField.setText(gender);
                dobTextField.setText(dob);
                addressTextField.setText(Address);
                postcodeTextField.setText(Postcode);
                ninTextField.setText(NIN);
                jobtitleTextField.setText(JobTitle);
                startdateTextField.setText(StartDate);
                salaryTextField.setText(Salary);
                emailTextField.setText(email);


            }



            resultset.close();
            statement.close();
            connection.close();
        } catch ( Exception e1 ) {
            System.err.println( e1.getClass().getName() + ": " + e1.getMessage() );
            System.exit(0);
        }

        }});
```

Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: You are iterating over the entire result set and effectively only displaying the last one (because you update your GUI fields on each iteration). Either you need to populate that `selectAllEmployees` list and use that as a data source in your GUI, or you need to move the iterating over the result set to your GUI (which BTW might not always be the right solution!).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Right, this makes sense. However, due to the selectAllEmployees being within a public void I cannot use the statement return selectAllEmployees.add(); I just get an error.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I tried to use selectAllEmployees.add(resultset.getString("id")); however, the .add keyword seems to have a problem. The method add(Employee) in the type ArrayList<Employee> is not applicable for the arguments (String). It suggests to change to addAll() however, when I do this I get the same error and the suggestion is to change to add().

Comment: Of course that doesn't work: you created a list that is supposed to contain `Employee` objects, of course you can't add a `String` to it. So: Create an employee object with the values from the result set, add it to the list, etc. And re: the return: it is your code, you need to change it so it performs the functions you need.

Comment: How do I append the values from the resultSet to my employee list? selectAllEmployees.add(resultset.getString(1));? This is the part I am really struggling with.

Comment: You don't, I repeat: create an employee object with the values from the result set, add it to the list, etc.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I already have one within my Employee Class?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel  public Employee(String Name, char Sex, String natIncsNumber, Date date, String address, String postcode, int ID, float Salary, Date Startdate, String Title, String Email) {
  super(Name, Sex,natIncsNumber, date, address, postcode);
  this.id = ID;
  salary = 0.0f;
  this.startDate = Startdate;
  this.title = Title;
  this.email = Email;
 }

Comment: But you are not creating instances of that class in the code shown.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel So Employee newEmp = new Employee(String Name, char Sex, String natIncsNumber, Date date, String address, String postcode, int ID, float Salary, Date Startdate, String Title, String Email) { super(Name, Sex,natIncsNumber, date, address, postcode); ?

Comment: I think you need to take a step back and learn some Java basics, for example how you instantiate classes (eg in the case `new Employee(name, gender, ...)` etc).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I know I'm not the sharpest when it comes to Java so apologies for my stupid questions. I have implemented all other features i.e. Delete, Update, Insert and even searching and I've finally got a clearer understanding. I think I need to assign a variable which keeps track of the employeeID (unique) and the next/previous button increments/decrements in accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

One of two things is happening. Either:

- You have a bug in the code which populates the database, so you *think* you have rows A, B, and C in the database, but in fact you only have row C

Or:

- Your code as listed populates your controls with the contents of row A, then it repeats to populate the exact same controls with contents of row B, and then the exact same controls once more with the contents of row C.  So, naturally, the values you are left with are the values of the last row.

It helps to think precisely what it is that you are trying to do, precisely what is happening, precisely what you expected to happen instead, and most importantly, what makes you believe that the code should do that which you expect it to do rather than what it actually does.

Comment: I can display different users using a certain field i.e. ID, Name etc. I currently haven't implemented a function to populate the database, rather with the use of SQLite I have added them in manually and retrieving them from the database.

Comment: Okay, then your problem is likely answered by my 2nd suggestion (3rd paragraph.)

Comment: Also, note that you declare `selectAllEmployees` but you are not using it in any way whatsoever, and even if you did, it makes no sense to declare it within the `while` loop.

Comment: I know it's a small tweak, I have access to the database which is critical. It does return a different record which is what I'm happy about, however, it just skips everything in the database and returns the very last entry. I have tried adding a counter to "count" the records individually as they are being returned. I have a feeling I have to modify/do something with while (resultset.next()) .

Comment: I used the selectAllEmployees within a while-loop as I searched here on StackOverFlow and I saw a thread where someone stated you must instantiate a new list within the while-loop and do it for each value you wish to return.